# How do I schedule a meeting for the 4th last Friday of a month?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Trying to schedule a meeting for the 4th last Friday (NOT the first Friday) of July, for example.

In 2022, that would be July 8
In 2023, that would be July 7
In 2024, that would be July 5

Comment: The last Friday might be the *fifth* one of the month. You question is self contradictory.

Comment: @drmoishe What is meant is the fourth Friday counting back from the end of the month. No self contradiction there. (Note the OP's examples.)

Comment: Don't know why this was voted as unclear, it is clear IMO, just 2/3 people misunderstood and gave invalid answers.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Outlook allows you to set the fourth last (or third last or second last) Friday (or any other day of the week) as a recurring schedule. (If it were possible, then setting Victoria Day in a calendar of Canadian holidays would be a set it and forget it thing, as that holiday is the second last Monday in May.) The best you can achieve is to set your event for the first Friday of July and adjust it in those years where the fourth last Friday in July is the second Friday and then back again when it is once again the first Friday.

Answer (score 1):

> Trying to schedule a meeting for the 4th last Friday (NOT the first Friday) of July, for example.
> In 2022, that would be July 8 In 2023, that would be July 7 In 2024, that would be July 5

4th is not necessary the "last", and the example you provide are actually all the "first" Friday. So, not quite sure about what exactly you want to do.

Anyways, any of the aforementioned scenarios can be achieved by playing around the options available in the **Recurrence** feature. See [Schedule events in Outlook for Windows-Create a recurring appointment or meeting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/schedule-events-in-outlook-for-windows-dee84520-3c7f-45a1-990b-98bbeca7ec31#:%7E:text=Create%20a%20recurring,Select%20OK.).

**Scenario 1 (4th Friday of July)**:

[image]

**Scenario 2 (Last Friday of July)**:

[image]

**Scenario 3 (First Friday of July)**:

[image]

Here's one more link with screenshots about how to schedule recurring meetings in Outlook: [Outlook Calendar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1189870/outlook-calendar).

Comment: The OP's first example is actually the second Friday of that month. What is meant by 'fourth last' is the fourth Friday from the end of the month going toward the beginning. (So, taking July, 2023 as an example: the 28 is the last Friday; the 21 is the second last Friday; the 14 is the third last Friday, and the 7 is the fourth last Friday.)

Answer (score 0):

When creating the meeting :

- Click the  "Recurrence" button in the ribbon
- Select "Yearly"
- Select "On the:"
- Select "fourth" / "Friday" / of "July"
- Complete the other parameters of the meeting
- Click OK.